# Operations on asymptotic notations

Tags: asymptotics

How to use algebra in operations that involve asymptotic notation?
Like for example:

- $C_1(n)= O(n)$
- $C_2(n) = O(n^2)$
- Is $C_2(n)/C_1(n) = O(n)$?

Comment: I don't think so the example works for big-O. It might work with big-theta I guess.

Comment: Related question: [Counterexample to big-O claim looks wrong](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/69785/9550).

Answer (score 1):

### Yes and no.

A function $f(n)$ is said to be $O(g(n))$ if there exists a constant $c$ such that

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{f(n)}{g(n)} \leq c
$$

Knowing this, a few things immediately become apparent:

- Addition and subtraction *preserves* the largest $O$ of the result, thanks to the properties of limits.

  For instance, $f(n) \pm h(n)$ are $O(g(n))$ if *both* $f$ and $h$ are
  individually $O(g(n))$.

  This is why you can say, if two operations are $O(n)$, then the resulting sum/subtraction is also $O(n)$.

  If either $f$ or $h$ were $O(n^{2})$, then the result would be $O(n^{2})$. This is in agreement with intuition.
- A function that is $O(n)$ is *also* $O(n^{2}), O(n^{3})$, etc. as you can prove by this definition.

  For practical purposes, that is immaterial, as you only usually care about the *smallest* upper bound.
- Multiplication *can* be simplified in the manner you require.

  For instance, say I have $f, h$ that are both $O(n)$. This means

  $$
     \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{f(n)}{n} < c\;\;\mathrm{and} \; \; \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{h(n)}{n} < c
     $$

  or, equivalently,

  $$
     \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(n) < \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} cn\;\;\mathrm{and} \; \; \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}h(n) < \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} cn
     $$

  I can then argue that $f \times h$ is $O(n^{2})$, since, when we go to calculate it, this would require:

  $$
         \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{f \times h}{n^{2}} < c
     $$

  which we can prove like so by substituting the inequalities above:

  $$
         \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{f \times h}{n^{2}} < \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{cn \times cn}{n^{2}} < c^{2}\;\;\mathrm{which\;is\;a\;constant!}
     $$

  In general, the product of two polynomial operations of order $O(n^{k}), O(n^{p})$ is at least $O(n^{k+p})$.
- Division is a bit trickier. Let's take your example: say we have $f, h$ both $O(n)$.

  We now try to calculate the limit, using the properties formally stated above, and find:

  $$
     \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{\frac{f}{h}}{n} < \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{\frac{cn}{cn}}{n} < lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{1}{n} = 0 < c
     $$

  so it *is* $O(n)$.

  But wait a minute! It is *also* $O(1)$:

  $$
     \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{\frac{f}{h}}{1} < \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{\frac{cn}{cn}}{1} < lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{1}{1} = 1 < c
     $$

  so the same operation is somehow *both* $O(1)$ and $O(n)$ at the same time.

  No, this is not some quantum spookiness at work. Remember that a function that is $O(n^{c})$ is also $O(n^{k})$ if $k > c$, as we stated above. Correctly speaking, it is not wrong to say either $O(1)$ or $O(n)$ or any other higher power (excluding deities).

  In such cases, you may want to use the much stronger $\theta$ definition, which says a function $f$ is $\theta(g(n))$ if $f(n)$ is $O(g(n))$ and $g(n)$ is $O(f(n))$ i.e. they grow at the same pace.

Comment: Your section about division is wrong. In particular, knowing that $\lim f, \lim h<cn$ does _not_ mean that $\lim(f/h)<cn/cn=1$. For example, consider $f(n)=n$ and $g(n)=1/n$. We have $f,g=O(n)$ but $f/g=n^2\notin O(n)$. To be able to upper-bound $f/g$, you would need an upper bound for $f$ and a _lower_ bound for $g$, but $O(\cdot)$ only gives you the upper bound.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot divide asymptotic notations in this way, since big O is only an *upper* bound. For example, if you take $C_1(n) = 1$ and $C_2(n) = n^2$ then $C_2(n)/C_1(n)$ is not $O(n)$.

If you're confused, think instead of the following question:

- Given $C_1(n) \leq n$ and $C_2(n) \leq n^2$, does $C_2(n)/C_1(n) \leq n$ necessarily hold?

Big O is very similar to $\leq$, the main difference being that we ignore multiplicative constants.